# Where can I find Category from Measurement Protocol in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I use the Measurement Protocol the [iv parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#iv)
But I can't see/find this category in Analytics. I see only the Enhanced E-Commerce category [`pr<productIndex>ca`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#pr_ca).

Comment: Iv is the item category.   What category exactly are you looking for.

Comment: @DaImTo : I set the iv=mycategory and looking for the category in Analytics. Like all in=myproduct in this category.

Comment: E,g, in the product performance report - you can set it as secondary dimension or switch the primary dimension to product category. Or you create a custom report. This might be off-topic, though, as it's a question about a GUI rather than about code.

Comment: @EikePierstorff i agree may be better for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is my problem. I can't see the Category (iv-Parameter) as a secondary Dimension. Only the enhanced e-commerce category prXca.